# Continue to next blob in the ForEach Block when there is an exception in the Catch block

Tags: c#, xml, linq, azure

I have many xmls in Azure Storage container. I wrote code to strip off unnecessary data elements from those xmls. To list all the xmls in different folder structures I used

```
var blobs = container.ListBlobs(prefix: <Root Location of Blobs>, useFlatBlobListing: true);
 foreach (CloudBlockBlob blob in blobs)
```

And to parse the xml I am using Linq.

The problem I am facing is there are few xmls that are missing the proper format or few xmls that doesn't have closing literals. I want to catch the exception and skip that xml file from processing and proceed to the next one. How can I do that using the Try catch block ?

The exception I get is `System.Xml.XmlException`

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
    foreach (CloudBlockBlob blob in blobs){               
             bool isError = false;   
            try   
            {                          
               // do your code here;   
            }catch(Exception ex){
                isError = true;
            }
           if(isError) continue;
        }
```

Update:

```
void Main()

    {
        string[] list = new string[]{"bob", "jack", "tom", "sparrow"};
        foreach(string li in list){
            try{
                if(String.Equals(li, "tom")){
                    throw new Exception("Fault");
                }
                Debug.WriteLine(li);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Prints:

```
bob
jack
Fault
sparrow
```

Comment: That whole isError flag is not needed.

Comment: @PeterBons : Then how can I continue to next blob when the current one has an exception ?

Comment: if you put a try/catch around your statements inside the foreach loop it is ok. So follow this answer without the isError stuff, it will automatically skip the failing blob.

Comment: @PeterBons : I did that but currently what my process does is it writes the error to an error log and job ends there... It doesn't go to next blob.

Comment: Ok, where does it fail. here: `var blobs = container.ListBlobs(prefix: <Root Location of Blobs>, useFlatBlobListing: true);` or inside `foreach (CloudBlockBlob blob in blobs)` ?

Comment: inside foreach (CloudBlockBlob blob in blobs)

I have a statement var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlfile1);  as the xml is out of format it fails there